# typeerror:null is not an object(evaluating cities.push)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm reading this book by manning publishing, react native in action, in the tutorial in chapter 6
Am trying to create an app that can be use for adding and displaying of city but while trying to add the city, I get this error

> typeerror:null is not an object(evaluating cities.push)

pointing to

> App.js line 42, column 11

and

> AddCity.js line 30, column 35

. And I don't really know what to do to slove the problem.

Actually, am following the react native in action tutorial by Dabit Nader

This is

> App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';

import Tabs from './src'

const key = 'state'

const initialState = [{
  city: 'Paris',
  country: 'France',
  id: 0,
  locations: []
},
{
  city: 'Tokyo',
  country: 'Japan',
  id: 1,
  locations: []
}]

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    cities: []
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let cities = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
      cities = JSON.parse(cities)
      this.setState({ cities })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error from AsyncStorage: ', e)
    }
  }
  addCity = (city) => {
    const cities = this.state.cities
    cities.push(city)
    this.setState({ cities })
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(cities))
      .then(() => console.log('storage updated!'))
      .catch(e => console.log('e: ', e))
  }
  addLocation = (location, city) => {
    const index = this.state.cities.findIndex(item => {
      return item.id === city.id
    })
    const chosenCity = this.state.cities[index]
    chosenCity.locations.push(location)
    const cities = [
      ...this.state.cities.slice(0, index),
      chosenCity,
      ...this.state.cities.slice(index + 1)
    ]
    this.setState({
      cities
    }, () => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(cities))
        .then(() => console.log('storage updated!'))
        .catch(e => console.log('e: ', e))
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs
        screenProps={{
          cities: this.state.cities,
          addCity: this.addCity,
          addLocation: this.addLocation
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

This is

> AddCity.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'

import uuidV4 from 'uuid/v4'

import { colors } from '../theme'

class AddCity extends React.Component {
  state = {
    city: '',
    country: ''
  }
  onChangeText = (key, value) => {
    this.setState({ [key]: value })
  }
  submit = () => {
    if (this.state.city === '' || this.state.country === '') alert('please complete form')
    const city = {
      city: this.state.city,
      country: this.state.country,
      id: uuidV4(),
      locations: []
    }
    this.props.screenProps.addCity(city)
    this.setState({
      city: '',
      country: ''
    }, () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Cities')
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Cities</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='City name'
          onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('city', val)}
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.city}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Country name'
          onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('country', val)}
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.country}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.submit}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add City</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#666',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18
  },
  heading: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 40,
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  input: {
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    height: 50
  }
})

export default AddCity
```

> react-navigation used is version 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are non primitive data types so they are reference by address.

In your code -

```
 addCity = (city) => {
    const cities = this.state.cities
    cities.push(city)
    this.setState({ cities })
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(cities))
      .then(() => console.log('storage updated!'))
      .catch(e => console.log('e: ', e))
  }
```

You are basically changing the cities array of state directly, Your `push` will mutate the state directly, do this instead -

```
 addCity = (city) => {
    this.setState({ cities: [...this.state.cities, city]})
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(cities))
      .then(() => console.log('storage updated!'))
      .catch(e => console.log('e: ', e))
  }
```

Same thing for other places. Hope this helps you.

Comment: The error showing now is TypeError:Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: @gbengaogunbule Hmm.. seems like it's not an array can u `console.log(Array.isArray(this.state.cities))` and tell what it logs?

Comment: `   let cities = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
      cities = JSON.parse(cities)` This may change it from array. I would suggest you to use proptypes to prevent such errors